# If I want to use 0.3g BBs in my AEG, do I need to upgrade my gearbox?

Tags: equipment, shooting, airsoft

As I understand it, upgrades to the gearbox usually give no real benefit to the range or accuracy, but might be required if there's too much strain on the lower-end stock gearbox (e.g. because of upgrades to the barrel, battery or, perhaps, BB size).

Is this understanding correct?  Should I upgrade my gearbox if I plan on using heavier BBs than the standard 0.2g?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding seems correct, however simply using heavier BB's will not increase the strain on the gearbox as the propulsion force for the BB comes from the spring. The spring is unaltered, therefore the strain on the gearbox is unaltered.